Emacs on Mac file opening behaviour
I am a very happy user of Emacs on Linux, and a far less happy one on Mac.
I can't seem to get one thing right: opening files from the command line, which I do with
open -a Emacs /some/file/path.txt

and never seems to open the file at the first shot.
Emacs 28.1 (9.0) on Sonoma

This works fine for me. I'm using Emacs from https://emacsformacosx.com, in case that matters. Have you tried open -a Emacs --args /path/to/file.txt?
